# Difference between "VerticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center " and "textAlign = TextAlign.Center on Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What is the difference in the code below between `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center` and  `textAlign = TextAlign.Center`?

```
 Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier.padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = message,  
            fontSize = 100.sp,
            lineHeight = 116.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
        Text(
            text = from,
            fontSize = 36.sp
        )
    }
```

I tried this code from Google's Android course and i want to know the difference between those two things.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The [`verticalArrangement`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement) is a [`Column`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Column(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal,kotlin.Function1)) attribute that defines how the children of the Column should be positioned. With `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center`, the children will be centered vertically.

[image: verticalArrangment]

The [`textAlign`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextAlign) is a [`Text`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Text(androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,kotlin.collections.Map,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle)) attribute that defines how the text should be aligned in the horizontal axis. With `textAlign = TextAlign.Center`, the text will be centered horizontally within the Text Composable.

> Defines how to align text horizontally. TextAlign controls how text aligns in the space it appears.

> TextAlign.Center 
> Align the text in the center of the container.

---

As a side note, please make yourself familiar with the Jetpack Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference), where you can find such information in the future. A simple Google search usually brings up the right resources.